# How to get libreadline for Android?

Tags: android, readline

I tried to download the gnu readline-6.2 source code but could not manage to build it on Android platform. Could anyone point out a way for me to tackle this problem? Thanks a lot!

I try to get the default Android build flags on my PC and use it to run ./configure and got problems saying that:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-linux-androideabi
configure: cross-compiling for arm-linux-androideabi is not supported

Beginning configuration for readline-6.2 for arm-linux-androideabi

checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-linux-gcc... /home/huangwei/ICS/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/home/huangwei/ICS/external/readline':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

However, I opened the config.log and use the same build command to compile the conftest.c, it works, the .o file is there. I don't know why the configure still fails. Is there anyone could help?

Comment: Since Android users are not typing things in on a command line, why do you need this? Beyond that, "could not manage to build it" is a completely useless description of your problem.

Comment: I am sorry for not describing the problem clearly, will update soon. I need this libreadline because I want to port lua-5.2.2 to Android which has dependency on this library.

Comment: If your objective is to embed Lua in your app, then you should not need the Lua files that require `libreadline`.

Comment: I understand. You mean if I don't need the LUA commandline then libreadline is not required, right? How ever, I need to run some LUA scripts from command line. So I need a full version of LUA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself also needing to compile libreadline for arm-linux-androideabi.  What I did was the following:

1. download source code for libreadline gnu.
2. set CC to the android-ndk cross compiler (`CC=~/android/lib/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`)
3. update the config.sub and config.guess files (the ones in the libreadline source are very old and don't have arm-linux-androideabi)

   `$ cp /usr/share/misc/config.{sub,guess} support/.`
4. run ./configure with --host and --prefix set to the target architecture and the locations for the compiled objects

   `$ CC=~/android/lib/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc ./configure --build=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=~/android/lib/`
5. `make && make install` and it worked for me!  I have `libreadline.a` and `libreadline.so` files in `~/android/lib/lib`

Note, before I had updated the `support/config.sub` and `support/config.guess` files I was getting the same error described in the question.

Comment: Yes this is exactly how I fixed this problem, but I forgot to post the answer here. But still thanks.